# Как преобразовать координаты фигуры в 3D пространстве?

Tags: opengl, 3d

Как правильно расчитать 3d координаты вершин объекта, чтобы он находился постоянно в одном положении относительно камеры (перед ней) при любых перемещениях и поворотах камеры и был всегда обращен к камере одной стороной?

Очевидно, что речь идет о матрице модели, которую надо строить по координатам точки "Look-To" и направлению вектора ("Look-To" - "Look-From"). Предполагаю,  что для этого можно использовать матрицу вида. Как правильно построить такую матрицу модели?

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю. Мне известен такой способ. Но меня увлекла сама задача - математически: в теории все красиво, а на практике никак не получается. И еще хотелось бы практически оценить, будет ли выигрыш в быстродействии однопроходного рендера от способа описанного вами.

Comment: @Kromster причём тут GUI ?

Comment: @ampawd посмотрите текст вопроса до правки, там упоминается HUD.

Comment: да, я вначале сравнил фигуру перед камерой с HUD, чтобы было более понятна суть вопроса. Но потом исправил - как коворят, "Правильно заданный вопрос - половина ответа". Извиняюсь перед Kromster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вначале хочу сказать про матрицы. Совершенно заморочили голову с этими преобразованиями. Так вот, матрицы нужны для шейдерного движка при расчете сцены. Если мы обсчитываем координаты одной фигуры в неподвижном окружении, то использование матриц не принесет ускорения расчета и понимание кода.

Я не зря написал в комментарии про "Правильно заданный вопрос". Действительно, именно обдуманная и исправленная формулировка вопроса помогла найти корректный ответ (C++):

```
    // исходное направление камеры: вдоль оси Х в сторону +
    // Построим перед камерой плоский прямоугольник, немного
    // сместив его (x = t) навстречу камере. После "сдвига" координат
    // при помощи сложения с вектором ViewTo это смещение
    // компенсируется.
    double s = 0.01, t = -0.9;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> p {
        glm::vec3(t,-s,-s),
        glm::vec3(t,-s, s),
        glm::vec3(t, s, s),
        glm::vec3(t, s,-s)
    };
    // каждую вершину поворачиваем на углы положения камеры и смещаем
    // на вектор ViewTo (к точке, на которую направлена камера).
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        p[i] = glm::rotateZ(p[i], look_zenith);
        // азимут отрицательный из-за реализации поворота в
        // в библиотеке GLM, не совпавшей с моей моделью вращения.
        p[i] = glm::rotateY(p[i], 0 - look_azimuth);
        p[i] += ViewTo;
    }
```

[image: демо сцена]

На изображении белый прямоугольник и есть плоскость перед камерой, которая всегда неподвижна относительно камеры.